# How to use ng-click for multiple + / - operators in same controller - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, increment, angularjs-ng-click, decrement

Hi i am new to angularjs. In my shopping cart app i am having three textfield for selecting quantity. All the three where loaded from the server. For each product i have to set different ng-click method to change the quantity. If i click one increment button, all the three quantity is changing. Please help me out

In controller:

```
$scope.increment = function(id) {
     if ($scope.count >= 50) { return; }
     var cou = $scope.count++;  
     //id = id+1;  
     $scope.total=$scope.price*cou;
 $scope.total=$scope.total+35;
   };
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="orders in ordersList">
                                 <a href="#"><span class="img"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/freslogo.jpg" alt="">
                                 </span><span class="product noproduct clearfix"><span class="name"> <b class="doller"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>{{orders.price}}</b></span>{{orders.product_name}}
                                 <span class="price">Order ID # {{orders.id}} </span>
                                 <span class="price">- {{orders.created_date}}</span> </a>
                                <div id="field1"><b>Qty:</b>                                    
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="spin-up" data-spin="up"><i id="plus" class="ion-plus-circled" ng-click="increment({{orders.id}});"></i></a>
                                    <input type="text" id="1" value="{{count}}" class="field">                                  
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="spin-down" data-spin="down"><i class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="decrement();"></i></a>
                                </div>
                              </li>
```

Comment: post your existing code so that people would be able to find actual problem and they will help you.

Comment: please find updated Code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.increment = function(orders) {
     if (orders.count >= 50) { return; }
     var cou = orders.count++;  
     //id = id+1;  
     $scope.total=$scope.price*cou;
     $scope.total=$scope.total+35;
   };
```

As you are using count for individual order but in controller part you are treating it at  the scope level. Try same for `decrement`

Comment: Hi i have some changes in passing the id while clicking increment button [ng-click=increment"({{orders.id}})"; and the value to {{count}}.

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you please check this code

Comment: Your requirement says that you need separate count for different orders but you are trying to use the common count for all the fields using `$scope.count`, so if you can just create a plnkr and share, I can analyze.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.increment = function(order) {
     if (order.count >= 50) { return; }
     var cou = ++order.count;  
     //id = id+1;  
     order.total = order.price*cou;
     order.total = order.total+35;
};
```

Comment: Hi i have some changes in passing the id while clicking increment button [ng-click=increment"({{orders.id}})"; and the value to {{count}}.